# using Hibernate-tools to update schema

Tags: eclipselink, database-schema, hibernate-tools

I am currently using EclipseLink JPA and in my persistence.xml file i have this property set

```
<property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="drop-and-create-tables"/>
```

The `value` field currently set to drop and create tables on each run is causing my test data to be deleted. Unfortunately, EclipseLink does not support an `update` schema property that integrates with any changes to Entities in my project. I read somewhere, Hibernate-tools can be used to update the database schema without deleting current records?

I have tried this property

```
 <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-tables"/>
```

while it does keep my data, it doesn't update table schema.

In my persistence.xml can i include the hibernate property ?

```
 property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"
```

Answer (score 1):

EclipseLink (as of 2.3.2) doesn't support DDL altering existing tables to add missing fields.  Please see feature request https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=368365

Comment: will this feature be added to upcoming releases?

Answer (score 0):

No, you can use only standart jpa properties or properties of your persistence provider (EclipseLink in your case). I believe that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4612187/eclipselink-does-not-generate-tables-from-annotated-jpa-classes) you will find your answer.

Comment: okay, i understand that i cant mix persistence provider's but the link you sent doesn't give an answer on how to set the property that tells EclipseLink to 'update' the schema. The value = 'create-table' according to EclipseLink will execute a CREATE TABLE SQL for each table. If the table already exists. I need it to update the schema without erasing the data

Comment: This is not impossible to update your database and save old data.

Comment: Note* this isnt for production but rather for development. It becomes annoying that i have to keep creating the same records as i am testing. Do you have an example?