# Persistence.xml not correctly configured

Tags: java, jdbc, persistence, ejb, jta

I'm not able to get this persistence file correct... I do not find any more information in the book that I use as a guide. I'm using a MySQL database.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
      <persistence-unit name="a11_DA_g5_PU" transaction-type="JTA">
        <jta-data-source>a11_DA_g5</jta-data-source>
        <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
        <class>entities.Book</class>
        <class>entities.Author</class>
        <class>entities.Customer</class>
        <class>entities.Membership</class>
        <properties>
          <property name="eclipselink.target-database" value="DERBY"/>
          <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver"/>
          <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://studev.groept.be:3306/a11_DA_g5"/>
          <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="a11_DA_g5"/>
          <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="passwordhere"/>
          <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-tables"/>
        </properties>
      </persistence-unit>
    </persistence>
```

**EDIT**

SEVERE: DPL8015: Invalid Deployment Descriptors in Deployment descriptor file META-INF/persistence.xml in archive [EJBModule_jar].
Line 6 Column 15 -- cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'provider'. One of '{"http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence":shared-cache-mode, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence":validation-mode, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence":properties}' is expected.

SEVERE: DPL8005: Deployment Descriptor parsing failure : cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'provider'. One of '{"http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence":shared-cache-mode, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence":validation-mode, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence":properties}' is expected.

SEVERE: Exception while deploying the app [VaadinTestApp]

SEVERE: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'provider'. One of '{"http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence":shared-cache-mode, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence":validation-mode, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence":properties}' is expected.
java.io.IOException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'provider'. One of '{"http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence":shared-cache-mode, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence":validation-mode, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence":properties}' is expected.

Comment: And what does the error message say? Error messages are intended to be read. I'm sure it doesn't just say "Something's wrong".

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Order of elements inside `<persistence-unit>` is important, `<jta-data-source>` should go after `<provider>`:

```
<provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider> 
<jta-data-source>a11_DA_g5</jta-data-source>
```

Comment: Ok, that seems to improve things. Getting another error now:
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'values IDENTITY_VAL_LOCAL()' at line 1

Comment: Note that `eclipselink.target-database` is `DERBY`, but connection URL points to MySQL.

Comment: Finding that strange as well, but I cannot find anything how to point it to MySQL. Can you show me the way?

Comment: @mmvie Change the value for that property to mysql

Comment: Okay, it works BUT I need to create the tables inside the database myself. My handbook is telling me it should create the tables itself once it creates the entities, do I need to enable that or is there some kind of setting/property in the xml?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4612187/eclipselink-does-not-generate-tables-from-annotated-jpa-classes does it! Thanks all!

Comment: Wow.  The _order_ of the elements matters?  I know that isn't really XML's fault at all, but still...one more reason to dislike XML.  Annotations, anyone?

Comment: @aroth annotations can get just as ugly.  Order may not matter as much but still...

Answer (score 10):

As [the XSD](http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd) says, the `<provider>` element must come before the `<jta-data-source>` element.

Comment: What determinate if elements should be in order or not is:
`xsd:sequence` (determinate order)
`xsd:all` (no order)