# JPA create-or-extend tables

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, persistence.xml

DDL generation "create-or-extend-tables" works with EclipseLink2.4. An extra column is created when i do JPA Tools-> Generate tables from entity. But why doesn't this alteration of table not happen automatically during deployment of application? Happens only when i manually use the JPA tool. Also there is an error shown in the file that read "Column XXX cannot be resolved" . Could somebody explain what happens in the background??

Comment: @DataNucleus please do not remove tags from peoples posts, this is a JPA question, even if it is specific to a provider

Comment: Does this answer your question? [EclipseLink "create-or-extend-tables" not working: "...unknown column..."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13372213/eclipselink-create-or-extend-tables-not-working-unknown-column)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar question, you can see the answer here along with some discussion.

[EclipseLink "create-or-extend-tables" not working: "...unknown column..."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13372213/eclipselink-create-or-extend-tables-not-working-unknown-column)